# Prove that the nullity of a matrix is $n-2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $u_1, u_2$ are two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $v$ is the orthogonal projection of $u_1$ unto $u_2$. $A$ is the $3 \times n$ matrix such that $u_1^T, u_2^T, v^T $ are the rows. Show that the nullity of $A$ equals $n-2$.

I was wondering if my solution to the exercise is correct:

By the rank nullity theorem we know that if the nullity of $A$ equals $n-2$, the rank of $A$ must equal 2. Since the projection is defined as $\text{proj}_{u_2}(u_1) =  \dfrac{u_2 \cdot u_1}{u_2 \cdot u_2} u_2$ and we know that $u_2 \cdot u_1 = 0$ because the vectors are linearly independent, the third row of $A$ is a zero-row and thus the rank is 2, meaning the nullity is $n-2$, concluding the exercise.

Comment: Linear independence does not imply $u_2\cdot u_1 = 0$. For instance, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are linearly independent, yes their dot product is $1$.

Comment: @Arthur Can we then say that the dot product is simply a number, so $v$ is simply a multiple times $u_2$? The word "orthogonal" in "orthogonal projection" kind of throws me off.

Comment: Yes, that's how I would see it. Orthogonal projection is simply one specific projection among many different ones (you can project non-orthogonally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $v$ is the orthogonal projection of $u_1$ onto $u_2$, we know that $v$ is some scalar multiple of $u_2$ (use definition orthognal projection). Then, $\beta = \{ u_1, u_2 \}$ forms a basis for the row space of $A$, because

(1) $\beta$ is a set of linear independent vectors.

(2) $\text{span}(\beta) = \text{row}(A)$.

The rank of $A$ is the dimension of the row space, therefore equal to 2. Using the rank theorem we conclude that $$\text{nullity}(A) = n - \text{rank}(A) = n - 2.$$